# Breeze always 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, breeze

I built a oData-Service which works well.
Now I want to query them with Breeze but I always get an 404 error.
In Fiddler I see first a 200 with empty Body and then follows the 404 with "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI".
But running in a normal browser the odata Service delivers the right data.

I debug it and set a breakpoint on the Server to see if the service is called correctly. After sending the request the breakpoint shows that the Service is called. But parallel to the break breeze calls the fail-method of

```
manager.executeQuery(query)
                    .then(querySucceeded)
                    .fail(queryFailed);
```

and e.message is empty.

Any idea??? :-/

***Next entry...***

I deactivate CORS and now I get the 404 immediately.

**Here is the request:**

OPTIONS xxx:8080/myDataService/odata/Person?$select=Name HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin:localhost:61244
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: dataserviceversion, accept
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:61244/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

**and here the answer:**

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 178
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Date: Mon, 19 Jan 2015 12:11:48 GMT

{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI xxx:8080/myDataService/odata/Person?$select=Name'."
  }
}

Comment: Include more details about the requests- I think you can copy them out of fiddler and paste them in your question.

Comment: The request is the same I can send with a browser and here it works.

Answer (score 0):

No surprise that the OPTION request passes; you've probably got the server set to say "OK" to every request ... and that's just fine for now.

The rejection has to do with the address of your GET request: `xxx:8080/myDataService/odata/Person`. Are you sure that's the right endpoint? The path is usually plural (`Persons`).

It's easy enough to just paste that url into a browser address bar and see what it does.

Comment: Hi Ward, nice to see a breeze developer ;-). Yes the endpoint is correct. I can copy the link in a browser and will get the right data from my Server. If not I wont get a stop at the breakpoint. I think it could be a Problem with the metadata (again...).

Comment: You're getting a 404 on the data request, not metadata request. It's not making sense to me that the URL copy-pasted from the error message actually works in the browser address bar. I guess next to try is composing the exact request sent in another tool like fiddler or postman until you can nail down what's different

Comment: I have a look with fiddler...
The GET is the same but this Header works (from browser Input):
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

This one not from breeze:
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
Origin: http://localhost:54004
DataServiceVersion: 2.0